# How to receive file from nodejs with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I need to axios to get a pdf buffer from nodejs and more some data info.

If I set the axios post with responseType: "arraybuffer", and I make node send only the pdf buffer it is working.

But I need to return some more data info from node and if I get rid off the "responseType:arrayBuffer", in order to receive a json, I am unable  to convert pdfBuffer to pdf with new Blob function. 
I get BLOB invalid.

What am I doing wrong?

This is not working:

//front end:

```
const resp=await axios.post("atestadosClientes/generatePDF", data);

 const file = new Blob([response.data.pdfBuffer], {
          type: "application/pdf",
        });
//Build a URL from the file
const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

//Node response:generate pdf buffer
return res.send({
      message: "Success",
      id: resp[0].insertId,
      pdfBuffer: pdfSignedBuffer, //pdf buffer
    });
```

This is working:

//front end:

```
const resp=await axios.post("atestadosClientes/generatePDF", data, {
      responseType: "arraybuffer",
    });
  },
const file = new Blob([response.data], {
          type: "application/pdf",
        });
//Build a URL from the file
const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

//Node response:generate pdf buffer

```
return res.send(pdfBuffer)
```